# Exporting Mappings from Informatica server

Tags: java, shell, batch-file, informatica, informatica-powercenter

My Requirement is to export mappings from informatica Server.i am using pmrep command for the same .Currently  i am running pmrep command on the machine on which informatica server is Installed and its exporting successfully on the same machine after running command.But My req is to run the command remotely from some other machine and want to store mappings on my local system not on the machine on which Informatica server is installed.Is there any possible way to do that. or some other command which do the needfull. Hope my Requirement is clear to all.Can anybody help me out  with some solution..

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to login to the informatica server using ssh and run the export. After the export file is created, you can do FTP to download the file to your local machine.

Comment: samik..yes exactly ..but i have to run the command remotely  through java[not ssh]..is it possible to run the[pmrep or any other command which serves the purpose] remotely through java program.

Comment: I guess you can use some third party libraries for ssh/ftp. I had used the jsch library sometime back. https://www.jcraft.com/jsch/

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a properly configured client machine. Try installing the client, run pmrep and get back with the details if you'd be getting any errors and would need some help.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a script once the mapping is imported in the server, move or copy the mapping in to your local path. The script should include the URL and password of the local machine.